# PHP (codeigniter) - How to check if the next two rows have value?

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

I wanted to check if the next **TWO** rows or **ID** is **not NULL**.

because if there is no succeeding **TWO** rows or **ID** then the income remains zero.

```
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
          if(($row->id + 2) != NULL) //I don't know what is the correct statement here
          {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row->id."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row->username."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>"."650.00"."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row->remarks."</td>"; 
            echo "<tr>";
          }
          else
          {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row->id."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row->username."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row->income."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row->remarks."</td>"; 
            echo "<tr>"; 
          }                  
        }
```

Here is the table I want to achieve.

```
==================================
|ID | Username | Income | Remarks|
| 2 | user1    | 650.00 |        |
| 3 | user2    | 650.00 |        |
| 4 | user3    |   0.00 |        |
| 5 | user4    |   0.00 |        |
==================================
```

If I add a username then the next output will be this:

```
==================================
|ID | Username | Income | Remarks|
| 2 | user1    | 650.00 |        |
| 3 | user2    | 650.00 |        |
| 4 | user3    | 650.00 |        |
| 5 | user4    |   0.00 |        |
| 6 | user5    |   0.00 |        |
==================================
```

Comment: and what is the problem? error? share some more info

Comment: The output Income of all my rows will be 650.00 when the original "IF" statement is running

Comment: you wanted to check if there is still a succeeding record after user2? am I right?

Comment: and please include the database structure and values. thanks.

Comment: Dude, please edit the question, add all the info, outputs, errors, everything, if the answer below is correct then mark it as such, remember - other people might benefit from your question, so take the time to write it properly so it will be clear, you can read the FAQ about how to properly write a question, it's for everybody to benefit from :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your foreach to get the index.

```
    foreach ($data as $index => $row)
```

Then you can address all rows relative to your current row with:

```
    $row_two_ahead = $data[$index + 2];
```

you should check however if that row exists before you try to use it or you will get index out of range exceptions:

```
    if (isset($data[$index + 2])) {
    }
```

Comment: by the way do you know what to code to use in getting the last index of the database?

$this->db->____?

Comment: I am not familiar with codeigniter. With pure SQL you would do: SELECT MAX(id) FROM table;

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem...

this is the code from my controller:

```
public function addUsername()
{
  $data['id'] = NULL;
  $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
  $data['reward'] = 0.00;
  $data['remarks'] = ' ';

  $this->Matrix_model->addUsername($data);
  $last = $this->Matrix_model->getLast();
  $index = $last - 2; //I minus the last index with two
  $this->Matrix_model->updateIncome($index); //and updated the income of that index
  redirect('http://localhost/matrix/index.php/matrix');
}
```

and this is the code from my model:

```
public function addUsername($data)
   {
    $this->db->insert("income", $data);
   }

public function getLast()
  {
    return $this->db->insert_id(); //this is the method to access the last id inserted
  }

public function updateIncome($id)
  {
     $this->db->set("reward", 650);
     $this->db->where("id", $id); 
     $this->db->update("income"); 
  }
```

**thank you and I'm sorry if other programmers didn't understand my questions**